# Code for conditional tag wordpress nav not working

Tags: wordpress

```
if (is_page_template( 'page_blog.php' ) ) {

    remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
    add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'genesis_do_nav' );

}
```

I would like to display the nav on the blog page archives only

Comment: More people seem to have this problem, maybe you can find a solution in this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is_page_template-refuses-to-acknowledge-the-default-page-template

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting the code?  It would need to be before header is included.

Also you could put something like

```
?><script>alert ("is page_blog.php");</script><?php
```

between the curly braces to make sure it is getting triggered at all.

Comment: The blog page template is part of the core parent theme so i don't want to edit it. I am using a child theme therefore i want to use its functions.php file for customization.

Comment: What i need to learn is how to add the conditional tag with the actions hook